# Charles D. Bingham is correct Inventor

Tags: us429497

In reference to the patent: [US429497](https://www.google.com/patents/US429497)

Not a question, just a correction, the inventor is Charles D. Bingham. My family bought his house from his daughter (Viola?) in Watertown NY and I lived there back in the 1980s. I remember finding old books and some of his hand made wooden gears and such, I wish I still had them.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is less than accurate optical character recognition. Old patents like this are scanned and text generated using OCR. At the bottom of the page you linked to is a link for sending feedback to Google if you would like them to fix the error. Interestingly, Google's other (and better) patent site has the inventor's name correctly transcribed: https://patents.google.com/patent/US429497A/en.

Please understand that this site is not connected to Google or the USPTO so posting your correction here has no impact on what is displayed on Google's site.